# What does this XSD Regex really equate to?

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I am having a hard time figuring out this XSD Regex match. Here is the simpleType defininition:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="data-fuelcorrfact">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
      <xs:pattern value="\-?[1-9]\.[0-9]{4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I can guess that it needs a number between 1 and 9, a period, and another number betwen 0 and 9. I don't understand what the `\-?` is and putting a value of 1.0 for example fails validation.

Can someone please help me decipher this regular expresion? Also, does anyone have any references for programs or websites that can explain a given XSD regex value should consist of? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with XSD, but assuming that is uses the usual RegEx rules, here's the breakdown:

First, `\-?`. That matches one or zero dashes, i.e. negative or not. The `\` is just an escape character, i.e. treat the `-` as an actual `-` character and not a special RegEx character. Outside of square brackets, though, it doesn't usually have any special meaning. Might be an XSD thing.

Next, `[1-9]` matches any non-zero numeral character (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9). So a single-digit number.

The `\.` does, in fact, match a period.

Then we have `[0-9]{4}` which matches exactly 4 numeral characters (including zero now).

So it's looking for any number in (-10, 10) but not in (-1, 1) with exactly four decimal places. Strange behavior; I suspect the `[1-9]` should be `[01-9]` because it's very weird to omit the values around 0 like that.

Comment: Thank you! That was my problem, missing the {4} required characters.

Answer (score 3):

You're quite close. The `\-?` is an optional minus sign, escaped by the `\`. I'm not terribly familiar with XSD so I can't say for sure if that escaping is actually necessary. `'1.0'` fails the validation because the regex demands exactly 4 decimal places – that's the `{4}` part of `[0-9]{4}`. `'1.000'` should match.

Answer (score 1):

The `-` is being escaped with the `\` - I don't believe this is actually needed, possibly someone trying to be safe (if the escaped character isn't special, it will be output as is).

It is followed by `?` meaning zero or one.

So, an optional `-` at the start.

`1.0` fails validation due to the `[0-9]{4}` after the `.` - this required four decimal points, where `1.0` only has one.

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) for an XSD regular expression reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the XSD specification, unlike nearly every other regex dialect, **does not allow** a hyphen to be escaped with a backslash. Your XML Schema processor appears to be excessively liberal in what it accepts.